# CASE Expression in DELETE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

## The issue

While looking for a good query as answer for [Side effects while combining two statements using Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733623/side-effects-while-combining-two-statements-using-cypher/32734554#32734554) I tried to make a CASE in DELETE part of the query, and I got a strange error...

#### Dataset

```
MERGE (p1:C5{userId:'1234'})
mERGE (p2:C5{userId:'555'})
MERGE (p3:C5{userId:'1234'})
mERGE (p4:C5{userId:'6969'})
MERGE (p1)-[r1:follow]->(p2) 
MERGE (p2)-[t1:follow]->(p1)
MERGE (p3)-[r2:follow]->(p4) 
MERGE (p4)-[t2:follow]->(p3)
SET r1.type='mirror',
t1.type='real',
r2.type='real',
t2.type='mirror'
```

#### Query

```
MATCH (n:C5 { userId: '1234' })<-[r]-(),
    (g:C5{userId:'1234'})-[y]->()
    DELETE  
        CASE 
            WHEN r.type = 'mirror' THEN r 
            WHEN y.type = 'real' THEN y END
```

#### Error message

`Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure: Relationship 3499 has been deleted`

I'm using Neo4j 2.2.5 on Mac Yosemite 10.10.5 and this has been done with an empty database cleared with this:
`Match (a)-[b]-(c), (d) delete a,b,c,d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several reasons why your query would not work properly.

1. The `MATCH` clause is finding **pairs** of `y` and `r` relationships, which means that the same relationship instance (let's call it "y1") would appear in multiple result pairs (say, "y1/r1" and "y1/r2"). Therefore, your query was trying to delete the same relationship more than once.
2. Your `CASE` clause would skip the `y.type = 'real'` test if the `r.type = 'mirror'` test happened to succeed. So, not all appropriate `y` relationships would be deleted.

Here is a simple query that filters out duplicates and deletes all appropriate relationships.

```
MATCH ()<-[y { type:'real' }]-(:C5 { userId: '1234' })<-[r { type:'mirror' }]-()
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT r) AS rs, COLLECT(DISTINCT y) AS ys
FOREACH (r IN rs | DELETE r)
FOREACH (y IN ys | DELETE y);
```

Comment: I was not looking for a solution to this, because the answer I gave to the question was not using this, I was just wondering why I got this error, and you gave me the answer I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

When I've encountered `Relationship XXX has been deleted` or similar in the past I got around this by using `WITH` and then performing a `DELETE`.

To take your exact Cypher and make it work all you need to do is the following:

```
MATCH (n:C5 { userId: '1234' })<-[r]-(),
    (g:C5{userId:'1234'})-[y]->()
WITH  
        CASE 
            WHEN r.type = 'mirror' THEN r 
            WHEN y.type = 'real' THEN y END as rel
DELETE rel
```